# Ionic ng-show working in Ripple but not on device

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-show

I use Ionic and AngularJS.
In layout.html I have:

```
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="header">       
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="bar-subheader">         
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
      <i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>
    </ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
     <a class="button button-clear ion-drag" ui-sref="app.menu" ng-show="$root.showPublicMenu"></a>
     <a class="button button-clear ion-drag" ui-sref="private.menu" ng-show="$root.showPrivateMenu"></a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view name="layoutContent">
  </ion-nav-view>

</ion-pane>
```

In the app.js I have:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if(toState.name!="otherwise"){

          if(toState.name=="app.menu"){
            $rootScope.$root.showPrivateMenu= false;
            $rootScope.$root.showPublicMenu= true;
          }
          else if (toState.name=="private.menu"){
            $rootScope.$root.showPrivateMenu= true;
            $rootScope.$root.showPublicMenu= false;
          }
        }

});
```

When I test this with Ripple it's working, but when I test the application on device, Android or IOS, doesn't work.

Any idea?